# How to set permissions on network interfaces?

Tags: macos, permission

At each reboot, the permissions on the network devices `/dev/bpf*` are changed.

As a developer, I want write acccess on these files. 
This can [easily be fixed with a `chmod`](http://regis.decamps.info/blog/2011/03/wireshark-does-not-detect-networks-cards-after-mac-os-update/).

What is the most elegant solution to fix this issue permanently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wireshark ships a `StartupItem` that does just that; however, the StartupItems API is deprecated:

```
 The SystemStarter utility is deprecated.  System services should instead
 be described by a launchd.plist(5).  See launchd(8) for more details.
 The launchd utility is available on Mac OS X 10.4 and later.

 In earlier versions of Mac OS X, the SystemStarter utility is used to
 start, stop, and restart the system services which are described in the
 /Library/StartupItems/ and /System/Library/StartupItems/ paths.
```

So, since you're asking for "the most elegant solution", that would be a launch daemon.

I haven't tried the following code, but it should be roughly correct.

Create a file `/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.stackexchange.apple.bpf-helper.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.stackexchange.apple.bpf-helper</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.stackexchange.apple.bpf-helper.sh</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And a file `/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.stackexchange.apple.bpf-helper.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
chgrp admin /dev/bpf*
chmod g+rw /dev/bpf*
```

Both should be owned by `root:wheel`. The first should be 644; the second 755 (600 and 700, respectively, will probably do as well).

You can use `launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.stackexchange.apple.bpf-helper.plist` to try it without a reboot.

Comment: [\[launchd-dev\] About the ServiceIPC key](http://lists.macosforge.org/pipermail/launchd-dev/2009-June/000570.html): `On Leopard and later, you can treat the ServiceIPC key as  
being inferred through the presence of a Sockets or MachServices  
dictionary. There's no need to explicitly specify it.`

Comment: Hadn't actually meant to leave that in there, since it should be irrelevant, but thanks. :)